# Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'u201944136_root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, html, hosting

I got stuck at this.
i am using hostinger for my website

```
    $server = "localhost";
    $user = ""; //Username
    $password = ""; //Password
    $database = ""; //Database
    $connection = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$password,$database);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      exit();
    }
```

This is my code.
i could not find a relevant answer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error is explicit, `Access is denied for user`. You need to sort this out with your hosting provider.

Comment: https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-connect-php-to-mysql

Comment: I am also using the official documentation of hostinger
but i dont know what is the issue
i am a beginner

Comment: Have you created the database and set up a user with a password for that database? You'll also need to give that user permissions like `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, etc. All that is done through the hosting provider's website. Reach out to them if you get stuck.

Comment: Everything is done. as documentation stats with permissions

Answer (score 0):

thanks for helping me.
it was hosting issue. i mailed to the support system of the hostinger.
they told me to change my database password and then update the script.
i follow the instructions and my error was solved.
Thank You All.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that localhost is the right host?
I would also dump the mysqli_connect_errno() value because it returns the error code from the last connection attempt, which will give you a very good indication of where the issue is.
and
I would check if the user u201944136_root is defined and have permissions against localhost (mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'u201944136_root'@'localhost';)